# Why can't I use request if I packing with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, request

I try to use Webpack to pack my React code.

Then I try to use request to get some information from Website.

This is part of my JS code

```
  rp({url:'http://int.dpool.sina.com.cn/iplookup',encoding:null})
        .then((html) => {
        this.setState({data:"sucess"})
    })
        .catch((err) =>{
        this.setState({data:err.toString()})
        })
```

I use rp, which is request-promise(request with promise) and I try to display the result by this.state.data.

The code ran in node well(without react and webpack), and I accessed data successfully. If I use Webpack to packing it, it shows me error :RequestError: TypeError: Failed to fetch.

I guess after I use webpack, there are some problem with the internet.

This is my webpack.config.js

```
let path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './App/app.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dest'),
        filename: 'app.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {   test: /\.js|jsx$/,
                loaders: ['babel-loader'],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders:['css-loader']
            },
            {   test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|svg|ttf)([\?]?.*)$/,
                loaders: ['file-loader']
            },
            {   test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    node: {
        console: true,
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty',
    }
};
```

I don't know whether the problem is I set the net to 'empty'.

If I ignore the

```
node: {
        console: true,
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty',
    }
```

webpack would return me some error

Comment: Have you tried removing the `node` object from your webpack config and running your bundled code?

Comment: Yes, I've tried.

If I remove node object it would show me 

ERROR in ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\weather-app\node_modules\request\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js 3:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/request/request.js
 @ ./node_modules/request/index.js
 @ ./App/app.js

And Can't resolve 'net',Can't resolve 'tls'........

Comment: You can add a source map to webpack which would allow you debug your code in a browser. See https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/

Comment: Thank you very much, I will have a try.